# Php Session value Increment

Tags: php, laravel, session

I was trying to create a logic where I need help of this `$_SESSION['visit']` incremented value.

What I wanted is that every time I reload my page, value of `$_SESSION['visit']` should increase by `1`, but its not working that way.

If you can please clear How I can achieve it and what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['visit']))
{
$_SESSION['visit']=0;
}

$session_value=++$_SESSION['visit'];
//echo $session_value;
?>
```

Comment: Where is the `session_start` call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read session values form another session instance in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332515/how-to-read-session-values-form-another-session-instance-in-php)

Comment: Why is your question tagged laravel, or why don't you use the laravel Session helper?

Answer (score 0):

CBroe answer is right. This is the code with session_start(); added.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['visit']))
{
    $_SESSION['visit']=0;
}

$session_value=++$_SESSION['visit'];
echo $session_value;
?>
```